# How can I add Hangul to this regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex to detect alpha-numeric, Kanji, Katakana, and Hiragana. I would like to add Hangul to this, but I'm not sure of the range:

> Regex.IsMatch(p.Name, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9ァ-ヾぁ-んー一-龠々]+$")

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three [Unicode categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks) you may add to your regex to support Hangul:

```
\p{IsHangulSyllables}
\p{IsHangulCompatibilityJamo}
\p{IsHangulJamo}
```

You may add them to the end of the character class:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9ァ-ヾぁ-んー一-龠々\p{IsHangulSyllables}\p{IsHangulCompatibilityJamo}\p{IsHangulJamo}]+$"
```

To support all CJK chars, you may consider adding

```
\p{IsCJKRadicalsSupplement}
\p{IsCJKSymbolsandPunctuation}
\p{IsEnclosedCJKLettersandMonths}
\p{IsCJKCompatibility}
\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionA}
\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}
\p{IsCJKCompatibilityForms}
```

too.